# Best practice for delayed operation?

Tags: apex, crud

I have request for delayed operation: When Contact(single record of the class) undergo specific conditions, wait 30 days and disable it.

I have option to implement it outside of Salesforce, but that is not very nice solution. So is there any best practice how to solve such situations? Some settable CRUD or named alerts? I am not limited by Apex -- I can manipulate with object model too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct tool for the job here is **[Time-Dependent Workflow Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)**. You can easily set up a `Workflow Rule` and set your criteria there, and then specify a time delay either from the date the rule was triggered, or any date/time field on the object.

[image: Workflow Time Trigger Edit]